# Documentation of placeholder options

Tags: r, officer

This is probably a very easy question to answer, but how can I find a list of options for placeholder arguments. In particular, ph_with_text(type = ...) For a Title and Content slide will accept type = 'title', while a Title Slide slide will not. It does accept 'ctrTitle'.  Is there a list/cheatsheet which lists the options and results of each?

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `annotate_base` to see all available layouts and PH id in a powerpoint file: https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/annotate_base.html